# remote connection between two android device

Tags: android, networking

How I can make a Remote connection between two android Devices as like a team viewer
and i have read this site http://anyremote.sourceforge.net/android-client.html but is connect remote on Pc.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you required the **root permission** for both the devices